# Pause before JQuery AJAX post

Tags: javascript, jquery

Because the page I am working on is an intranet page, my AJAX call is very quick along with the response. For usability purposes I'd like a short 1-2 sec pause to display a loading animation. Below is what I have tried but the animation is barely visible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#wait').hide();
    $('#submitform').click(function(){
    $('#wait').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "abs_newabs_check.asp",
        data: { StaffID: $("#suggest1").val() },
        success: callback
    });

});
});

function callback(data, status)
{
    $('#wait').hide();
    $("#ajaxdiv").html(data);
}
```

Comment: "I want to make my application slower", what an interesting idea :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a setTimeout call to the callback function:

```
function callback(data,status) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#wait").hide();
    $("#ajaxdiv").html(data);
  }, 1500);
}
```

nb. the data parameter will be passed into the anonymous function as a closure, if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 5):

I would have to suggesting thinking about a different way to add usability you are now slowing down your service to help users. What about using the [Yellow Fade Technique](http://37signals.com/svn/archives/000558.php) That way you can show something has changed on the page and you are not slowing down your system.

Here is a related question that may help. [Yellow fade Effect with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848797/yellow-fade-effect-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for that. I have implemented that along with my loading animation.

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout function

```
setTimeout("alert('5 seconds has passed.');",5000);
```