# Highlight changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <textarea>Original Text</textarea>
    <button>Replace</button>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
 $('button').click(function () {
     $('body').html($('body').html().replace('Original','New'));
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r7MgY/

Can I highlight changes somehow with a fading yellow background maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sarfraz says, use the jQuery color plugin. Usage is the same as animate method in jQuery. The plugin overrides the animation methods for these properties: 'backgroundColor', 'borderBottomColor', 'borderLeftColor', 'borderRightColor', 'borderTopColor', 'color', 'outlineColor'.

jQuery animate method usage and info can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Also, if you want to replace something in the HTML it's better to get the wrapper tag of the tag that contains what you want invoke the replace method on instead of search through the entire body as a string. Normally you'd use:

```
$('#idOfMyWrapperTag').html().replace('this', 'that')
```

But since you are using a textarea you can get it's value with this:

```
$('textarea').val().replace('this', 'that');
```

..fredrik

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it's better to use selectors than to search the body as a string.

Answer (score 3):

Because its a textarea, you cant inject any html directly into the content. You would have to overlay an absolute positioned element containing a red squiggle or similar - which becomes a bit of a nightmare when working out the exact location of the text.

If possible, ditch the textarea and just use an editable div or similar.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I highlight changes somehow with a
>   fading yellow background maybe?

You will have to use the **[jquery color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt)** to fade the background color.

Comment: Thanks, but there's no documentation available for the plugin. :(

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to workaround it with

```
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function () {
     $('body').html($('body').html().replace(/Original/g,'<span class="fade" style="opacity: 0; background-color: yellow;">New</span>'));
     $('.fade').animate({
        'opacity': 1
     }, 1000, function(){
        $(this).contents().unwrap();
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: Only thing to keep in mind with this is that the text inside the span will also fade.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to include yet another plugin, you can simply use a little jQuery code to accomplish a fading overlay:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function() {
   $(this).each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.before("<div/>")
        el.prev()
            .width(el.width())
            .height(el.height())
            .css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "background-color": "#ffff99",
                "opacity": ".9"   
            })
            .fadeOut(500);
    });
}

$("#target").highlight();
```

Credit goes to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11589350/1145177