# Highlight search text in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to highlight the search terms in the text area.

I have one text Filed,search Button and text area.

Quote ...

```
After i have enter the search string in the text field whenever i click the search button it highlight the search terms which is available in the text area and focus the search term in text area.

I have try to do this by using jquery.

But in mozilla,I can't get the focus to the search term at the time of search.

I have to scroll down the text area for find the focused search term.

In I.E. also it doesn't work properly.
```

Otherwise if any post related to highlight search term in text area is also appreciable.

Please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: define 'highlight'. You can't really highlight anything within a textarea, you may select a range and thats it.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863641/highlight-changes/2863719#2863719

Answer (score 2):

On Internet Explorer, I'd combine the use of [TextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533042.aspx) object with the [boundingTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533540.aspx) property value.

Comment: Those are IE-only and proprietary, which limits this solution to working in IE only.