# plugin to indicate a form element value has been changed

Tags: jquery

A date selection HTML form section contains two drop downs - one for the day of the month, the other for the month.

When selecting an invalid date such as 31st February, the day value is automatically updated to be valid (29th in the case of this form).

I would like to unobtrusively highlight this automatic change to the user with a JQuery effect  - for example, bu modifying the border of the updated element somehow, temporarily.

Does anyone know of any JQuery plugins that could help here?

Comment: If you're saying February has 29 days, you'd better be checking the year as well....

Comment: Yes, I know. In my particular instance, the year is unspecified and the 29th Feb is permitted. But thanks for the helpful comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the yellow fade effect (it highlights an area in yellow and then slowly fades away).

Here's a JS Fiddle example using a dropdown box:
http://jsfiddle.net/8tag2/

And here's another SO question on the subject that might be useful:
[Yellow fade effect with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848797/yellow-fade-effect-with-jquery)