# Scroll after editing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a number of anchor tags on my page that look like this

```
<a name="scroll_112_11" id="scroll_112_11"></a>
```

There is a tag for each entry in the database. The tag is generated according to values that come out of the database. So the page is basically a list of people and information pertaining to that person. Each entry has an anchor tag like the one above next to their name. 
After the entry is edited the page is redirected and should scroll down to the name of the person who was just edited. So the redirect looks something like this.

```
<?php
header('Location: mypage.php?#scroll_112_11); 
?>
```

This all works great for most of the entries on the page. The problem is that is does not work for the entries on the bottom of the page. I assume the reason why it does not work is because the page has not finished displaying all of the information for the entries on the  bottom of the page. Meaning that the browser is looking for

```
 <a name="scroll_112_11" id="scroll_112_11"></a>
```

and when it does not find it, it just goes to the bottom of the page and stops.

...not sure if I explained this very clearly, so excuse me if I end up having to reword it...

I do not know as much as I should about Javascript, but I assume there is a Javascript or jquery solution to this???

any ideas??

Comment: The browser simply can't scroll past the bottom of the document. However, the [yellow fade trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848797/yellow-fade-effect-with-jquery) is a good compromise that works on most browsers, and can be [implemented in pure CSS](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/yellow-fade-technique-css-animations).

Comment: Are you using exactly what you pasted? `<a name=scroll_112_11" id="scroll_112_11"></a>` is not exactly valid HTML.

Comment: @nl-x: Missing the opening quote in the `name` attribute, which is going to evaluate to something messy. Check out the output of the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) on that small string.

Comment: If it's a matter of the data not being fully rendered to the screen, you might want to explore the possibility of using something like [Open Ajax Hub](http://www.openajax.org/member/wiki/OpenAjax_Hub_2.0_Specification).  Depending on how you load your data, you might be able to publish an event that says "all data is loaded and rendered".  Some where else in your code, you would then subscribe to that particular event.  When that event is fired, you could do something like: $(document).scrollTop( $("#scroll_112_11").offset().top );

Comment: Yes Anthony the problem is that "all data is not loaded or rendered". I will try putting that function in the body tag and using the onLoad event...

Comment: Thank You Anthony!! That worked great! ...also thank you esqew but that was not the exact html so the html was actually correct.