# How to set effect dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yh6tza8r/1/), i tried to add a row dynamically only knowing the id of one of the previous  element of the table. The code works perfectly, otherwise i want to beautify it. In particular i wish to highlight the new inserted row, using this property:

```
.effect("highlight",  color: '#4BADF5'}, 1000);
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like there's an error in your fiddle- I don't think you ever actually close the function onClick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yellow fade effect with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848797/yellow-fade-effect-with-jquery)

Comment: @mskfisher, it's not a duplicate.. here i want to highlight the row  just added nth position after a known id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you need to add the jQuery UI lib.

Second - your algorithm is not optimal one.

Please find an optimal solution below:

```js
var myClick = function() {
  var nome = "Hello";
  var rowId = "120"
  var row = "<tr><td>" + nome + "</td></tr>";
    
  var newTr = $(".mytable1 tr #" + rowId).parent().after(row);
  newTr.next().effect("highlight", { }, 2000);
};

$('#button').click(myClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Add"/>
<table class="mytable1">
  <tr><td id="12">1.0</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="20">1.1</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="120">1.2</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="260">1.3</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="2">1.4</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="100">1.5</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="23">1.6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes your code works well, but i want to insert the new row nth position below the known id, and not after the last element of the table! Can u edit your code? Thanks so much