# Yellow fade effect using JQuery in MVC4

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have looked at a previous issue someone was having with having a yellow fade effect occur when a view is reloaded after an edit or delete to a table row.

[Yellow fade effect with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848797/yellow-fade-effect-with-jquery)

So my issue is this.  I can get the code to work correctly if I place this `<div id="target">Highlight Me</div>`into the view.  It highlights correctly each time the page is loaded.

My issue is that when I place a table row inside this div with other cells etc it doesn't highlight.  I'm fairly new to jQuery and MVC 4 so any help would be much appreciated.

My view code is as follows:

```
  @model List<SecureFileUploadTraining.Models.FilesUpload> 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Uploader";
}

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/YellowFade.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
<hgroup class="title">
    <!--<h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>-->
    <h1>@ViewBag.Message</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.sqlString</h2>
</hgroup>

<article>
<div id="target">Highlight Me</div>

<h4>Manage My Files</h4>
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    <table>
     <th>Filename</th>
     <th colspan='2'>Expiry date</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th colspan='3'>Actions</th>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
         <div id='target'>
         <tr>         
         <td>@item.Original_file_name</td>
         <td>@item.Expiry_date.ToShortDateString()</td>
         <td>
         <img src='~/Images/extend.png' width='13px' onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExtendExpiry", "Upload", new { File_id = @item.File_id })'" alt="Extend expiry date"/>
         <img src='~/Images/minus.png' width='13px' onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ReduceExpiry", "Upload", new { File_id = @item.File_id })'" alt="Reduce expiry date"/>
         </td>

         @if (@item.File_status.ToString() == "Deleted")
         {
              <td><span class ="deleted">@item.File_status</span></td>
         }
         else
         {
             <td><span class ="current">@item.File_status</span></td>
         }

         @if (@item.File_status.ToString() == "Deleted")
         {
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>
             @Html.ActionLink("Restore", "RestoreFile", new { File_id = @item.File_id })
             </td>
         }
         else
         { 
             <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { OriginalImageName = @item.Original_file_name, ImageName = @item.Current_file_name, ImageType = @item.File_type })
             </td>
            <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Access", "ManageAccess", new { File_id = @item.File_id, File_name = @item.Current_file_name })
            </td>
            <td>
             @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteFile", new { File_id = @item.File_id })
            </td>
         }
         </tr>
         </div>
     }

     </table>

}
else
{
     <h4>No files currently available.</h4>
}

 <p>* 
 @Html.ActionLink("Upload Files", "FileUpload", "FileUpload", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</h4></li>
 </p>
 <hr /><p>* 
  @Html.ActionLink("View files available to download", "Downloader", "Download", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</h4></li>
 </p><hr />
 </article>
```

The function code to create the highlight effect is:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        $("<div/>")
        .width(el.outerWidth())
        .height(el.outerHeight())
        .css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": el.offset().left,
            "top": el.offset().top,
            "background-color": "#ffff99",
            "opacity": ".7",
            "z-index": "9999999"
        }).appendTo('body').fadeOut(1000).queue(function () { $(this).remove(); });
    });
}

$("#target").highlight();
```

I'm unsure what I need to do to get it so that when a user clicks the Delete or the + or - icons the page reloads and the correct row is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

How can you write `<tr>` tag inside a `DIV`?

Don't use DIV, assign a id to each row with a little trick of concatenating item-id to avoid repetitive ids. Like this,

```
<table>
     <th>Filename</th>
     <th colspan='2'>Expiry date</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th colspan='3'>Actions</th>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
         string tmpId = "target_" + item.id;
         <tr id='@tmpId'>
         <td>@item.Original_file_name</td>
         <td>@item.Expiry_date.ToShortDateString()</td>
         <td>
         <img src='~/Images/extend.png' width='13px' onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExtendExpiry", "Upload", new { File_id = @item.File_id })'" alt="Extend expiry date"/>
         <img src='~/Images/minus.png' width='13px' onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ReduceExpiry", "Upload", new { File_id = @item.File_id })'" alt="Reduce expiry date"/>
         </td>

         @if (@item.File_status.ToString() == "Deleted")
         {
              <td><span class ="deleted">@item.File_status</span></td>
         }
         else
         {
             <td><span class ="current">@item.File_status</span></td>
         }

         @if (@item.File_status.ToString() == "Deleted")
         {
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>
             @Html.ActionLink("Restore", "RestoreFile", new { File_id = @item.File_id })
             </td>
         }
         else
         { 
             <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { OriginalImageName = @item.Original_file_name, ImageName = @item.Current_file_name, ImageType = @item.File_type })
             </td>
            <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Access", "ManageAccess", new { File_id = @item.File_id, File_name = @item.Current_file_name })
            </td>
            <td>
             @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteFile", new { File_id = @item.File_id })
            </td>
         }
         </tr>
     }

     </table>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: This has helped thanks but I'm still unsure how to call the correct #target in the jQuery function as it's currently looking for #target